# How I can save excel file in php?

Tags: php, excel, api

When I click the button, get data from database and make a excel file and download it.

I click the button and use curl to request at url,

```
<?php 
    $PlaceIdx = $_REQUEST['Idx'];
    $Day = $_REQUEST['Day'];

    $url = '#url';

    $post_data["Idx"] = $Idx;
    $post_data["Day"] = $Day;

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: appliaction/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($post_data));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo print_r($res,true);
?>
```

and receive it make excel file,

```
$filename = "TextExcel".'.xls';
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Tasks-Overview");

            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );   
            header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");   

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,"Excel5");
            $objWriter->save('php://output');

            exit;
```

And it occurs error like this on web browser,

��ࡱ�;��   ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������   !"#$%&'()����+,-���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������Oh��+'��0P(0 <�H�@5�����@5�����    � ��B�=�%r8X"1��Calibri��� �   ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � � �  �"�  �"�  �"�  �"�    �"�    �"�  �"�  �����8�������������������������������3f������ff���f����������������������������������̙��̙3f�3���������fff����3f3�f333�3�3f33�333�$�Tasks-Overview��g����\�ٳ��(Ƙ̅�/ ����ǌ�)tմ��l� ��� ����<�0�\�ٳ����Xֽ���T������� ��}���/4����01012143324323U�xǐ� 1���֥���1�����D���|���}���    �������\�ٳ|ǐ�\�ٳ��� (00:00~24:00)������ ٳX�D�q�t� 2000-04-0301088887777 2018-04-0616:46:38 ~ 16:46:59O�q�t� 2017-10-1101000000000 � ��*+������&ffffff�?'ffffff�?(�?)�?�"dXX333333�?333333�?U}}}}}}}}  � � � � � � � � � �   �  � � �  � � @� � � � � � � @� � � � � � � >�@d��d�Bgg����� ����՜.��+,��0�HPX`hp x�� WorksheetFeuilles de calculRoot Entry��������  �F5�����5������SummaryInformation(���� �F�Workbook������������  �F�   DocumentSummaryInformation8������������   �F*�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

But, when I just put php url on webbrowser address, it save excel file successfully.

I don't know why and which one is problem.

If you know about it, please help me.

Comment: Are you outputting anything before the `header()` calls? Is that `print_r()` part of the same script?

Comment: @jeroen Unfortunately, it is not

Comment: @PolarisNation Have you tried just to remove the echo part?

Comment: @Lucarnosky Yes when I remove echo print_r($res,true); this part, it does not show the message, but not download excel file too

Answer (score 0):

I use PHPExcel class too, and this is the class I've wrote to download the file, try it

```
public function download($filename = ''){
        if(empty($filename))
            $filename = date('d-m-Y h.i.s');
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'".xls');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel,'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

Where `$this->excel` is just a new instance of PHPExcel called like this

```
$this->excel = new PHPExcel();
```

Let me know if it make the trick